# Incorrect Windows 7 "No Internet Access" notice

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking, internet

In Windows 7, I have a WiFi network that shows up with a warning icon overlay and the "No internet access" description as shown in this image:

[image: No Internet Access]

The other network shown there is a VirtualBox VM, and is expected to show that way.

Plainly, this notice is wrong as I have been browsing with that connection all afternoon and used it to post this question.

**What makes this message come up, and how can I make it go away?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured this out.  In the "Internet Options" control panel applet there's a "Lan Settings" dialog with a "Autodetect proxy settings" checkbox.  Unchecking that seems to have helped things.

**Update** A much better explanation of what is going on can be seen here:
http://blog.superuser.com/2011/05/16/windows-7-network-awareness/

Comment: I have the same problem at home, but on a wired network, I get the red cross saying no network - even though the connection works fine with internet and local network. I will try your answer when I get home and report back!

Comment: I can confirm that this did not work for me :-(

Answer (score 0):

For me, it helped to restart the *Network Location Awareness* (NlaSvc) service.